# In Node.js, spawn a process with `{shell: true}`, and then communicate with the actual process instead of the shell

Tags: node.js, child-process

Say I am executing `nodemon index.js` using spawn and `shell: true` which will run:

```
/bin/sh nodemon index.js
```

I want to listen to restart messages from nodemon as documented [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/events.md#using-nodemon-as-child-process).

```
cp.on('message', event => ...)
```

I also would like to send messages to force a restart.

```
cp.send('restart')
```

---

### Why?

I am writing a generic process runner (think a better npm-scripts). It would not know whether the user is going to enter `nodemon index.js` or `echo 1` for example.

### Ideas

I could use strace or something to listen to the app events.